# What is the asymptotic distribution of the variance of the error term (in MLE linear regression)

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

In most treatments of the MLE linear regression, the author focuses on the asymptotic normality of $\hat \beta_{MLE}$. To estimate $Var(\hat \beta_{MLE})$, which relies on $\sigma^2$, they also show how to derive $\hat \sigma^2$, i.e. a consistent estimate of $\sigma^2$.

But what is the asymptotic distribution and variance of $\sigma^2$? Could you point me to a text deriving this?

Comment: But surely if it is a maximum likelihood estimator (or a function of it), its asymptotic variance can be found from the Fisher Information matrix, which in the regression model is diagonal. Unless I misunderstood your question, of course.

Comment: No the question is that simple! This is just a asking-for-reference question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptotic distribution of the MLE is normal with variances and covariances determined by the (inverse) Fisher Information matrix. Therefore, it all comes down to deriving this matrix for the normal linear regression. A detailed derivation may be found, among others, in Hayashi's "Econometrics", pages 47-53.